# Is the "is" redundant here?

Tags: sentence-construction, redundancy

The two sentences:

> 1. The lighter the camera, the harder it is to hold steady.
> 2. The lighter the camera **is**, the harder it is to hold steady.

I just saw the former one but always make the construction like the latter one.

Is the **is** redundant here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly idiomatic to use sentence 1.

Sentence 2 is OK also, but 2 letters longer.

---

You can read more [**here**](https://www.englishgrammar.org/thethe-comparative-adjectives/) about "The…the… with comparative adjectives":

> Structure: the + comparative adjective + clause + the + comparative adjective + clause
>
> - The more adventurous it is, the more I like it. (NOT The more it is adventurous, the more I like it.)
> - The less I see him the more I like him.
> - The more he reads, the less he understands.
> - The older we grow, the wiser we become.
> - The higher you climb, the colder it gets.
> - The richer one grows, the greater one’s worries.
> - The less you spend, the more you save.
> - The sooner they go, the better it is.
>
> A short form of this structure is used in the expressions ‘the more the merrier’ and ‘…the better’.
>
> - ‘How do you like your coffee?’ ‘The stronger the better.’
> - ‘When should I start?’ ‘The earlier the better.’

Comment: Isn't  *to hold **it steadily*** better?

Comment: I think they are both OK, with a difference in meaning. I cannot explain the difference, maybe somebody will enlighten us both :)

Comment: Can I say: "Greater the price smaller the demand"?

Comment: You can, of course, but it is definitely incorrect. The idiom has a very fixed structure, as described.